# asp.net mvp pattern. how easily move data from view into presenter

Tags: asp.net, mvp

I am using mvp pattern in small project. I have problems with view which contains html table with data(always 9 rows). How can i easily get data from html table and send it to the presenter? On the model side i want to keep data from html table as a generic `List<some_type>`

regards

Comment: how can I read this html table in my view? by HtmlTable class or in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Read the table in the view page, and push it to the presenter through an event.  Pass the data through an event argument.

HTH.